# Get secure url in html video tag using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video

I am using PHP code to generate a secure video URL. I want to ask how to use the video URL output by PHP in the HTML video tag. I have listed both below.

PHP video URL generation code -

```
  <?php
$securityKey = 'token_security_key';
$path = '/pathto/file.jpg';

$expires = time() + 5000; 

$hashableBase = $securityKey.$path.$expires;


$token = md5($hashableBase, true);
$token = base64_encode($token);
$token = strtr($token, '+/', '-_');
$token = str_replace('=', '', $token);  


$url = "https://myzone.b-cdn.net{$path}?token={$token}&expires={$expires}";  
echo $url;

?>
```

This generates a secure URL. But I do not know how to insert that URL in the source src in video tag. Please do help.

```
<video>
    <source src="LINKMP4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll trust you know the implications of your link signing efforts, but things involving MD5 hashes and Base64 encoding, at first glance, do not scream "good security practices".

---

On the question of how to put the URL in the src attribute, just echo it in that location in the page:

```
<video>
    <source src="<?php echo url; ?>" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

The same as you did above.

Answer (score 0):

*your file should have .php extension

```
<source src="<?php echo $url; ?>" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php code inside video tag.

```
<video>
    <source src="<?php echo $url; ?>" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```